# REST patch test operation

Tags: c#, json, rest, testing, patch

From [JsonPatch in ASP.NET Core web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
I have understood if I send the following description in a patch request

```
[
{ "op": "test", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": "foo" },
{ "op": "replace", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": "dummy" }
]
```

the replace operation should only be performed if the current value for /a/b/c equal to 'foo' ([rfc6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.6)).

However, I have currently the problem that I would like to test if /a/b/c has the value 'foo' OR 'bar' and if true then process the replace action. I want to avoid that the client has to send the request twice, one time with { "op": "test", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": "foo" } and if this fails { "op": "test", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": "bar" }. Is there a nice way to achieve that?